# Spyder: how to show only dataframe columns when hitting the tab key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, jedi

I am switching from `Matlab` to `Python` and I am facing the first hurdles. :)

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
T = pd.read_csv("MyFile.csv", sep=';')
```

So far, so good, but I have two problems:

1. In the console: when I type `T.` and then I hit `TAB`, I get listed *all* the columns of the dataframe along with *all* the possible commands that I can perform on `T`. How should I do to get listed **only** the dataframe columns?
2. In the editor: when I type `T.` followed by `TAB`, it takes long time before I see anything listed.

I wish the following behavior: when I type `T.` and then I hit `TAB` (or some other key) I shall get listed **only** the columns of the dataframe that I can then select by using the arrow keys on my keyboard.

I am running on `Windows 10` with `Spyder 5.1.5` installed through Anaconda and I also have `jedi` installed (but I don't know if it is active though, but on the bottom of `Spyder` I can see `LSP Python: ready`).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `Column names`. Here's how:

```
print(list(T.columns.values))
```

Or simply:

```
print(list(T))
```

Also, till now there might be no way to get column names with arrow keys or any other key.

I don't exactly know what could be the reason for your second question. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369681/spyder-on-macos-typing-is-very-laggy). Even though it's about MacOS but it might help.

Comment: Edited. There is also a question missing.

Comment: @UbaldoTiberi I have edited my answer. Kindly take a look at it.